# Unable to expand my partition with unallocated space

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I was a Windows10-Ubuntu dual boot user. Since I was not using Ubuntu much, I decided to delete the Ubuntu partition being used by Windows.

I deleted the Ubuntu partition, and have a lot of unallocated space now (about 275 GB). I keep trying to expand my current Windows disk but keep getting the error

> There is not enough space available on the disk(s) to complete this operation

If I try to create a new simple volume instead from the unallocated space, I get this error

> The size of the extent is less than the minimum

I am quite new to this, and therefore, am quite stumped. Would help if you guys could suggest a way for me to end up using the unallocated space; preferably without losing any data.

Attaching a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You will need a third party partition tool to do what you want, unless the unallocated space is just right of the windows partition, windows cannot do it.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to recommend any third party partition tools and are any of them free?

Comment: https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have an EFI partition at the end of the D: partition. This will need to be moved to the end of the drive before Windows will allow you to make use of that extra space. *Ideally* that EFI partition *should* be at the *beginning* of your (D:) drive. But in any case. That's the gist of your problem. If this weren't Windows, this would a fairly simple task. Your best bet for success in/with Windows will be to get third party software -- Partition software. But **beware**, do NOT attempt to use "free" versions of these products! I just finished evaluating 3 free (trial) versions of software for doing this, and all 3 failed. So be careful, and do some research before committing to anything.

HTH