What hinders SSD partitions from being expanded when non-consecutive unallocated space is available?
What hinders SSD partitions from being expanded when non-consecutive unallocated space is available?
With hard disk drives (HDDs), a partition cannot be expanded unless there is unused (empty) space physically (and immediately) after it on the platters.  This makes sense due to the physical nature of hard disk drives.
After experimenting with solid state drives (SSDs) in Linux and Windows, I see that a partition still cannot easily be expanded unless there is unused space immediately after it.  This doesn't make sense to me, given that the physical structure of SSDs are irrelevant.  Due to wear leveling, SSDs use space on all their non-volatile memory chips for a partition, no matter where it is located logically.
What hinders SSD partitions from being expanded (increased in size) if there is unallocated space on the SSD, but that unallocated space just happens to not be logically immediately after the partition in question?
Or is this simply an issue of the predominant tools included with modern operating systems not keeping up with technology?
(Please note that there are third-party tools out there that will allow this functionality, typically by moving a bunch of data, and often with bad results (see e.g. https://superuser.com/a/1448214/380110). But unless I'm missing something, I don't think Windows can do this natively, and many Linux distros do not include tools to handle this task.)

It has never been about physical structure of anything, but the structure of partition table/entry (that they are designed to store one range of LBAs for each partition, for obvious reason). Whether the storage mapped to the LBAs are contiguous is irrelevant in this.

Or, if you are thinking of possible "facilities" that allow the user to perform low-level operation like changing the LBAs of mapped storage, it's because it's dangerous and niche.

"What hinders SSD partitions from being expanded when non-consecutive unallocated space is available?" - This limitation does not just effect SSDs but also HDDs and virtually all storage devices.

@Ramhound Exactly.  And, to me, it makes sense for HDDs because of their physical limitations, but I'm having trouble understanding why this is the case for SDDs because they do not have the same physical limitations.

@TomYan So is it an issue of of the partition tables simply not supporting non-contiguous structures, and no one has implemented an improved partition structure all these years?

@EndAntisemiticHate There's nothing to be improved -- you don't want the fundamentals to get more complicated than just (start, end). If you need "more dynamic" stuff, you have e.g. LVM on Linux. Supporting ranges of LBAs in one partition means that partition table/entries cannot have a fixed size.

@EndAntisemiticHate - The reason your unable to combine two partitions that are not consecutive is not a physical limitation of either SSDs or HDDs.

"What hinders SSD partitions from being expanded ..." - Because the interface that the host uses to access the logical blocks still has the same constraints as an HDD. You're arguing that the FTL should be ignored while expanding a partition, and then the host should use ??? to access the drive. If the host does not continue to use LBAs, then a lot of filesystem calculations break.

Commenters are using the acronym "LBAs", which is confusing.  I've always thought "LBA" stood for "Logical Block Addressing", which is an addressing scheme, and thus a plural of the acronym isn't really used.  But commenter's use of "LBAs" indicates that people think it means something else that can be pluralized.  Does LBA mean something else?  I often like to assume I'm the most confused person in the room, and I probably am, but, um "LBAs"?  Is "CHSs" now in use too?

Some of these comments can likely be expanded into quality answers.

"Does LBA mean something else?" - Yes. LBA = Logical Block Address. So "LBAs" is  Logical Block Addresses.

@sawdust I don't think the internet agrees. LBA is an acronym for Logical Block Addressing, not Address.  For example, see https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Logical+Block+Addressing & https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/logical-block-addressing-LBA & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing & https://pcpartsgeek.com/lba-logical-block-addressing/ & https://ecomputertips.com/glossary/lba & https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/what-is-lba.html

@sawdust But now I understand that commenters are using "LBAs" to mean addresses, which is what really matters most in this context.  It's just a shorthand (or misunderstanding... it doesn't really matter) commenters were using that was confusing me.  Thanks for clarifying.

"I don't think the internet agrees" - So be it. But to professionals (as opposed to end-users) the authoritative source is the ATA/ATAPI Specification. Refer to Section 3.1.37 LBA (Logical Block Address).

@sawdust Thank you for the reference.  Much appreciated!


What hinders SSD partitions from being expanded when non-consecutive unallocated space is available?

LBA. Partitions have a starting sector and ending sector (or length). To do what you propose, you would have to create a new scheme to replace LBA.

What hinders SSD partitions from being expanded (increased in size) if there is unallocated space on the SSD, but that unallocated space just happens to not be logically immediately after the partition in question?

If the "unallocated space just happens to not be logically immediately after the partition in question", then there would have to be another partition defined after the partition in question or the unallocated space would have to occur before the partition in question. Either way under LBA, the starting address of a partition or partitions would have to be changed. With LBA, there is no way to change the starting address without also copying sectors.

Or is this simply an issue of the predominant tools included with modern operating systems not keeping up with technology?

Perhaps in the future there will be a new scheme, where addressing will be by partition number and a sector offset within the partition. This would not only require changes to operating systems, but also the creation of a new partitioning scheme, and changes to the firmware used by computer and SSDs.

The OP mentions "bad results" using current tools. Below I address this issue.
Apple Silicon Macs requires the use APFS, which allows one or more versions of macOS to be installed without the need for repartitioning. Apple only provides the means of installing other operating systems through virtualization. You can add and remove APFS volumes with repartitioning.
Linux has LVM, which allows a partition to have multiple volumes. Also, there is GParted which can move and resize partitions. This may require booting from external media to perform some operations. For example, Linux Live flash drives often include GParted.
Windows offers Dynamic Disks, but evidently this is being depreciated. For basic disks, there are free tools such as MiniTool Partition Wizard, which can move partitions. (I would still recommend backing up important files first.) With MiniTool Partition Wizard, you specify the operations to perform first, then the computer reboots to perform the operations without user interaction. When finished, the computer boots back to Windows.

It's just far simpler to use gparted (or etc) to move the partition in the way then to re-architect the partition table.  Also you could just create a D: or E: drive in the unpartitioned space and put files there.
First, SSD ONLY move sectors around for the purpose of wear leveling.
You don't understand the complexity of modifying the partition table GPT or MBR in this fashion.  All previous OS would not support the new partition scheme and therefore older systems would not boot a hard drive in the new scheme.
For example the HP Z400 could not boot a GPT partitioned drive because the BIOS could not understand GPT.  It ONLY knows MBR.  The first OS to support GPT is windows 7 so a vista PC could not even use a GPT formatted drive.
So in order to support your GPTX (GPT extended or whatever you want to call it) every BIOS on every device would have to be modify with the new code.  In addition, all OS currently in use would have to be modified to support GPTX.  There are limits as to how many sectors the GPT can use so running out of space is an issue and changing the limit causes even more legacy (anything pre GPTX) issues.
You would have to convince 100's of companies to adopt GPTX, and given the complexity and millions of dollars spent in development and implementation of GPTX the companies would just tell you NO.
The MAIN reason for GPT is to allow UEFI which affects the overall security of the whole PC.  It does correct a number of oversights like only allowing 4 primary partitions and drives over 2TB.  These are real quality of life improvements, that are necessary and unavoidable.
Given the simplicity of using GPARTED (or etc) to move the partition, and/or the ability to put a new partition in the unallocated space relativity easily it is very unlikely you would convince anyone to spend the money to create GPTX.  All you have to do is go into disk management, right click on the unallocated space and do a new partition.  Then save some of your file in the new drive.
I have used gparted 100's if not thousands of times without corrupting or damaging the partition table or the OS.
